# python3 failed to import cv2

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I used python2.7, and have installed opencv, I import cv2 successfully while use python2.7. But when I tried to use python3.4 to import cv2, it said No module named 'cv2',how can I import cv2 with python3

[image]

Comment: Have you tried re-installing OpenCV3?  When I switched from Python 2 to 3, I had to reinstall (both on my computer and with `pip`) to get it working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to install openCV for python3 - you can specify which version of python you'd like to use:

for python3:

```
python3 -m pip install opencv-python
```

for python2.7:

```
python2.7 -m pip install opencv-python
```